# API погоды, чтоб включала в себя температуру моря

Tags: php, api

openweathermap, worldweatheronline, wunderground не включают в себя температуру моря (или я не докопался). Мне нужно где-то получить температуру допустим Азовского или Черного моря. У кого-то есть варианты? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2):

На сайте

https://pogoda.turtella.ru/Sea_of_Azov/sea_temperature/

Запрос из отладчика

POST https://pogoda.turtella.ru/ajax/getBoundsResorts/

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но там только крымские города, мне нужно именно Азовское море.

Comment: @MishaRodnoy если только по азовскому, то вот держи, а поиск урла и формата уже за тобой 
http://kirillovka.ks.ua/azov-sea-water-temperature/
https://pogoda.turtella.ru/Sea_of_Azov/sea_temperature/

Comment: Как раз этот сайт открыт со вчера и сейчас ищу на нем, но с него можно выудить только html iframe, где будет погода+ температура воды. Но мне нужно пилить свой виджет , т.е. нужны просто данные.

Comment: @MishaRodnoy обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, но всё же не могу понять каким способом получить температуру воды Азовского моря

Comment: @MishaRodnoy там в объекте ответа есть поле seaTemp, его и берите, в пост передавайте две точки по диагонали и ширину с высотой (не знаю чем они есть эксперимент покажет)

Comment: Вот для ресурса worldweatheronline  запрос выглядит так: http://api.worldweatheronline.com/premium/v1/marine.ashx?key=MY_KEY&q=45.5217439,37.13378906&format=xml. А каким образом выглядит ваш запрос, нет ли документации?

Comment: @MishaRodnoy То что вы показываете это GET,а то что я это POST, в отладчике посмотрите, какие поля передаются в POST, там есть x1,x2,y1,y2, width, height. Документации нету так как это "чужое" API